# Menubar in UIWebview not showing up on first longpress action

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, menubar

So this problem is a little tricky. Basically, I found that the menu bar won't pop up in a UIwebview the first time you long press on a word. It would show something like this:
[Example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWqKn.png)

The words are selected, but the menubar is now showing. However, the second time you longpress on another word,the menubar just pops up fine.
[Example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3e1T.png)

Also, if you tap anywhere in the UIwebview or scroll it before longpressing on a word, the menu bar also shows up. It's just when the long press action is the first action you have with the UIwebview, the menu bar won't show up.

I checked this problem with some other third-party web browsers on app store (firefox, chrome). The same problem exists. However, Safari does not have this problem. Also, my iPad 2 does not have this problem either. But my iPad air does, so do the xcode simulators.

Not sure if I'm describing this problem clearly, thanks in advance for anyone that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is kind of Bug in iOS 9 web view
Me and my colleague was having same discussion yesterday.
Also it is only on Web view,Messaging apps works fine

Comment: Yea, this problem happened after I updated Xcode. Maybe Apple will fix this   bug.